# Drag and Drop из RecyclerView в другой View

Tags: android, recyclerview, view, drag-n-drop

RecyclerView находится под кастомным View. 
Как можно сделать так, чтобы элемент RecyclerView можно было перетягивать как внутри RecyclerView, так и в View?